# Can't do a proxy for an npm repository in Cloudsmith with Nexus 3

Tags: npm, nexus, nexus3

I want to configure a proxy with Nexus for a private repository in cloudsmith.io.
When I configure the proxy with the public npm registry everything works good, but when I configure the proxy with the Cloudsmith repository the command npm install fails.

To authenticate with Cloudsmith (without proxy), the .npmrc file must contains this:

```
registry=https://npm.cloudsmith.io/<my org>/<my repo>/
//npm.cloudsmith.io/<my org>/<my repo>/:username=<my user>
//npm.cloudsmith.io/<my org>/<my repo>/:_password=<my password in base64>
```

So I on the proxy configuration I enabled the http authentication, but a 404 is being returned.

have you idea if I missed somenthing on the proxy configuration?
Maybe Nexus can't deal with the Cloudsmith authentication.

Update:

Nexus logs:

```
2019-06-21 14:10:58,736+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: ignoreCookies
2019-06-21 14:10:58,736+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
2019-06-21 14:10:58,737+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Opening connection {s}->https://npm.cloudsmith.io:443
2019-06-21 14:10:58,840+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to npm.cloudsmith.io/13.249.122.86:443
2019-06-21 14:10:58,840+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Connecting socket to npm.cloudsmith.io/13.249.122.86:443 with timeout 20000
2019-06-21 14:10:58,841+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
2019-06-21 14:10:58,841+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
2019-06-21 14:10:58,841+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Starting handshake
2019-06-21 14:10:59,270+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Secure session established
2019-06-21 14:10:59,270+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
2019-06-21 14:10:59,270+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
2019-06-21 14:10:59,270+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  peer principal: CN=*.cloudsmith.io
2019-06-21 14:10:59,271+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  peer alternative names: [*.cloudsmith.io, cloudsmith.io]
2019-06-21 14:10:59,271+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  issuer principal: CN=Amazon, OU=Server CA 1B, O=Amazon, C=US
2019-06-21 14:10:59,271+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connection established 172.19.0.2:48268<->13.249.122.86:443
2019-06-21 14:10:59,271+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-52: set socket timeout to 20000
2019-06-21 14:10:59,271+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Executing request GET /myorganization/javascript/cordova HTTP/1.1
2019-06-21 14:10:59,271+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2019-06-21 14:10:59,271+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2019-06-21 14:10:59,271+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-52 >> GET /myorganization/javascript/cordova HTTP/1.1
2019-06-21 14:10:59,272+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-52 >> Host: npm.cloudsmith.io
2019-06-21 14:10:59,272+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-52 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
2019-06-21 14:10:59,272+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-52 >> User-Agent: Nexus/3.16.2-01 (OSS; Linux; 4.4.0-139-generic; amd64; 1.8.0_212)
2019-06-21 14:10:59,272+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-52 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
2019-06-21 14:10:59,804+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-52 << HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
2019-06-21 14:10:59,804+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-52 << Content-Type: application/json
2019-06-21 14:10:59,805+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-52 << Content-Length: 71
2019-06-21 14:10:59,805+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-52 << Connection: keep-alive
2019-06-21 14:10:59,805+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-52 << Date: Fri, 21 Jun 2019 14:10:59 GMT
2019-06-21 14:10:59,805+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-52 << Allow: GET, PUT, HEAD, OPTIONS
2019-06-21 14:10:59,805+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-52 << ETag: "2d642f304a79cbf4e5fe6270af0846ca"
2019-06-21 14:10:59,805+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-52 << Vary: Cookie
2019-06-21 14:10:59,805+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-52 << Server: Cloudsmith MCP
2019-06-21 14:10:59,805+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-52 << Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; child-src 'self' https://fast.wistia.net https://giphy.com https://intercom-sheets.com https://js.stripe.com https://player.vimeo.com https://share.intercom.io https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://www.intercom-reporting.com https://www.youtube.com; connect-src 'self' https://api-iam.intercom.io https://api.intercom.io https://api-ping.intercom.io https://api.stripe.com https://app.getsentry.com https://bam.nr-data.net https://www.google-analytics.com https://js.intercomcdn.com https://nexus-long-poller-a.intercom.io https://nexus-long-poller-b.intercom.io https://nexus-websocket-a.intercom.io https://nexus-websocket-b.intercom.io https://rs.fullstory.com https://sentry.io/api/ https://stats.g.doubleclick.net https://uploads.intercomcdn.com https://uploads.intercomusercontent.com https://widget.intercom.io https://yt0blqw1vlv7.statuspage.io wss://nexus-websocket-a.intercom.io wss://nexus-websocket-b.intercom.io https://api.cloudsmith.io https://api-prd.cloudsmith.io https://cloudsmith-package-uploads-prd.s3.amazonaws.com https://cloudsmith-package-uploads-prd.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com; font-src 'self' data: https://js.intercomcdn.com https://fonts.gstatic.com https://assets.cloudsmith.media; frame-src 'self' https://fast.wistia.net https://giphy.com https://intercom-sheets.com https://js.stripe.com https://player.vimeo.com https://share.intercom.io https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://www.intercom-reporting.com https://www.youtube.com; img-src 'self' data: https: https://downloads.intercomcdn.com https://gifs.intercomcdn.com https://gravatar.com https://img.shields.io https://js.intercomcdn.com https://static.intercomassets.com https://uploads.intercomusercontent.com https://assets.cloudsmith.media https://prd.cloudsmith.media https://users.cloudsmith.media; media-src 'self' https://giphy.com https://js.intercomcdn.com https://assets.cloudsmith.media https://prd.cloudsmith.media https://users.cloudsmith.media; object-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: https://api.stripe.com https://app.intercom.io https://bam.nr-data.net https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/ https://cdn.ravenjs.com https://connect.facebook.net https://fullstory.com https://js.intercomcdn.com https://js.stripe.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://maps.gstatic.com https://nexus-long-poller-a.intercom.io https://nexus-long-poller-b.intercom.io https://rum-static.pingdom.net https://sentry.io/api/ https://sjs.bizographics.com https://tagmanager.google.com https://tpc.googlesyndication.com https://translate.google.com https://widget.intercom.io https://www.googleadservices.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://www.googletagmanager.com https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/ https://assets.cloudsmith.media; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://tagmanager.google.com https://assets.cloudsmith.media; worker-src 'self' blob: https://assets.cloudsmith.media; form-action 'self' https://api-iam.intercom.io https://messenger-apps.intercom.io https://intercom.help https://cloudsmith.io https://www.cloudsmith.io https://prd.cloudsmith.io https://web-prd.cloudsmith.io; report-uri https://sentry.io/api/195170/csp-report/?sentry_key=85cf84319e204994878d7afb03753450
2019-06-21 14:10:59,805+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-52 << Public-Key-Pins: pin-sha256="++MBgDH5WGvL9Bcn5Be30cRcL0f5O+NyoXuWtQdX1aI="; pin-sha256="klO23nT2ehFDXCfx3eHTDRESMz3asj1muO+4aIdjiuY="; pin-sha256="tFOU95aPSUFNfZLpf6OdBnVvAFKxd8zxp4jCbaL3MJ0="; max-age=86400; report-uri="https://cloudsmith.report-uri.io/r/default/hpkp/enforce"
2019-06-21 14:10:59,806+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-52 << Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=5184000
2019-06-21 14:10:59,806+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-52 << Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
2019-06-21 14:10:59,806+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-52 << Expect-CT: enforce, max-age=86400, report-uri="https://cloudsmith.report-uri.io/r/default/ct/enforce"
2019-06-21 14:10:59,806+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-52 << X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
2019-06-21 14:10:59,806+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-52 << Via: 1.1 24990d51e53375dffbe8411f5e14f579.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
2019-06-21 14:10:59,806+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-52 << X-Amz-Cf-Pop: ATL51-C1
2019-06-21 14:10:59,806+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-52 << X-Amz-Cf-Id: _igVXHch2JQA54gLS1Btz7iTlbtc1W4PQ7S_Jrc4sKYvFwvMsJ5VBg==
2019-06-21 14:10:59,807+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Connection can be kept alive for 30000 MILLISECONDS
2019-06-21 14:10:59,807+0000 INFO  [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpclient.internal.HttpClientFacetImpl - Repository status for myorganization-javascript-proxy changed from READY to AVAILABLE - reason n/a for n/a
2019-06-21 14:10:59,807+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-52: set socket timeout to 0
```

Comment: 404 generally doesn't indicate auth problem, it generally indicates the package isn't there (or the repo isn't there).  What do you see on the CLI side?

Comment: This is returned by the cli:
`npm i cordova@8.0.0
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: cordova@8.0.0

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-06-25T15_36_57_248Z-debug.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that Sonatype Nexus expects the upstream request to be challenged with a "401 Unauthorized" response + a valid WWW-Authenticate header, rather than a "404 Not Found" response.

The indication that this is the issue is in the log output at:

```
2019-06-21 14:10:59,271+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2019-06-21 14:10:59,271+0000 DEBUG [qtp2116157452-1644] admin org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
```

Here, `UNCHALLENGED` states that Nexus will not be providing credentials, neither pre-emptively nor as a follow-up request. So if the target upstream is private and requires authentication, as in this case, this will cause the proxying to fail.

To fix this, the upstream will need to fix the response to return "401 Unauthorized" for the protected endpoint. This will ensure that the authentication is passed through to the target upstream. Assuming your credentials are correct, you should be authenticated.

It's also worth noting that, as of writing, Nexus does not support Bearer-based (token) authentication [1], so it isn't compatible with the `npm login` workflow. So make sure authentication is configured directly in `.npmrc` as username/password. For example:

```
registry=https://npm.cloudsmith.io/<my org>/<my repo>/
//npm.cloudsmith.io/<my org>/<my repo>/:username=<my user>
//npm.cloudsmith.io/<my org>/<my repo>/:_password=<my password in base64>
```

[1] https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-12456